# SAS: Screen Scraping Javascript

Tags: web, sas, screen-scraping

I am trying to screen scrape a series of tables like this:

http://www.aetna.com/docfind/pinSearch.do?pinSearchType=npi&pin=&npi=1356387815&provType=medical&sortBy=name&secureStatus=N&site_id=provider2&tabKey=pinsearchtab&langpref=en&sortOrder=ASC&pinSearchInd=Y&pinSummaryFlowInd=Y&sortBy=name&prefilledPlan=&prefilledProductCode=&x=62&y=10

The tables on the website are generated with JavaScript, and when I use the SAS filename url command, it doesn't seem like it is able to download the table.

Is there a way to scrape JavaScript tables using SAS?

Comment: It's unlikely since the data isn't being stored in an HTML format or a readable format. You're honestly probably better off emailing Aetna and asking for an excel file, they'll likely be willing to help, depending on your stated usage of course.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)?

It's headless webkit in javascript, and used with CasperJS (utility built on PhantomJS) you can manually scrape these websites pretty easily.